# Firebase on service, will stop working afer leaving the app on background for a while

Tags: android, service, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's the thing, my app has a service (extends Service) in charge of establishing a socket connection and listen for incomming network trafic using firebase native android framework. Here's what it looks like

```
public class SocketService extends Service {

private Firebase firebase;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    firebase = AppHelper.getInstance().getFirebase().child(AppHelper.getInstance().getFirebase().getAuth().getUid());
    AppHelper.getInstance().categoriesController.setListeners(firebase.child("categories"));
    AppHelper.getInstance().tablesController.setListeners(firebase.child("tables"));
    AppHelper.getInstance().itemsController.setListeners(firebase.child("items"));
    AppHelper.getInstance().requestsController.setListeners(firebase.child("requests"));
    AppHelper.getInstance().ordersController.setListeners(firebase.child("orders"));
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    AppHelper.getInstance().categoriesController.removeListeners(firebase.child("categories"));
    AppHelper.getInstance().tablesController.removeListeners(firebase.child("tables"));
    AppHelper.getInstance().itemsController.removeListeners(firebase.child("items"));
    AppHelper.getInstance().ordersController.removeListeners(firebase.child("orders"));
    AppHelper.getInstance().requestsController.removeListeners(firebase.child("requests"));
    AppHelper.getInstance().clearUserData();
    AppHelper.getInstance().waiter = null;
    AppHelper.getInstance().setConnectionState(false);
}
}
```

As you can see onStartCommand returns START_NOT_STICKY, so the service won't get killed as soon as I leave the app (on the background - middle button)

Here's how the AppHelper works:

```
public class AppHelper extends Application {

private static AppHelper instance = null;
private static Bus bus;
public TablesController tablesController;
public OrdersController ordersController;
public ItemsController itemsController;
public RequestsController requestsController;
public CategoriesController categoriesController;
private Firebase firebase;
public Waiter waiter;
private boolean connected = false;
public static AppHelper getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
public Bus getBus() {return bus;}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
    bus = new Bus();
    tablesController = new TablesController(this);
    ordersController = new OrdersController(this);
    itemsController = new ItemsController(this);
    requestsController = new RequestsController(this);
    categoriesController = new CategoriesController(this);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    firebase = new Firebase("https://restapp.firebaseio.com/");
    // other setup code
}

public Firebase getFirebase() {
    return firebase;
}

public void clearUserData() {
    tablesController.clearData();
    ordersController.clearData();
    itemsController.clearData();
    requestsController.clearData();
    categoriesController.clearData();
}

public void setConnectionState(boolean connected) {
    this.connected = connected;
    bus.post(new NetworkStateEvent(connected));
}

public boolean isConnected() {
    return connected;
}
}
```

Each controller registers a firebase listener to a corresponding node, Here's how the base class looks

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> {
protected Handler handler;
protected Firebase node;
protected ArrayList<T> models = new ArrayList<>();
protected ChildEventListener eventListener;

public BaseController(Context context) {
    handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    eventListener = getEventListener();
}

public void setListeners(Firebase node) {
    this.node = node;
    node.addChildEventListener(eventListener);
}

abstract ChildEventListener getEventListener();

public void removeListeners(Firebase node) {
    models.clear();
    node.removeEventListener(eventListener);
}

public ArrayList<T> getItems() {
    return models;
}

public void clearData() {
    models.clear();
}
}
```

So, here's whats happening. Everything works great, if you leave the app on background and come back it still works, you can even start other applications, lock the device etc etc. 
But, if you leave the app on background long enough (10 minutes or so) when you come back firebase won't respond. The app does NOT crash, but it doesn't do anything, it's as it was offline. I'm guessing something is getting gargabed collected. But I don't kwnow what that might be.

I tried This

```
connectedRef = new Firebase("https://restapp.firebaseio.com/.info/connected");

    connectionStateListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            AppHelper.getInstance().setConnectionState(connected);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
            System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
        }
    };
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(connectionStateListener);
```

And showed a message on the user's fragment whenever firebase get's disconnected. When I come back to app after 10 minutes, this message is not there ( that firebase is connected?).

Thank you in advance!.

Comment: Is this really the minimal amount of code needed to demonstrate the issue? It's hard to tell what is relevant here and what is superfluous, or to untangle all these undefined methods and guess which one actually contains the problem.

Comment: When your app is backgrounded, the OS can (and does) decide to close the socket connections after some period of inactivity. When it is restored, Firebase will restore than connection. It may take some short time frame to do this. If you're using goOffline() anywhere, I'd carefully examine that code.

Comment: Thanks for answering!. I'm aware that android might stop my service/socket connections if it's running out of memory. But I don't think my service is getting destoyed, when it happens it sets AppHelper.getInstance().waiter to null, which prevents the activity from starting. So I know the service wasn't stopped. This might be a problem particular to my app. I doubt anyone can help me. I will post the answer if I find it. :(

Comment: I begining to suspect that the problem occurs when the phone enters in "deep sleep". Android shuts down all power consuming operations, and sockets are defenitely one. I suspect this because 1. It never happened to me on an emulator and 2. Never happened on my device when pluugged in via usb. I might be wrong though, I'm looking for a way to dismulate this deep sleep behaviour on android

Comment: I don't think it requires anything special to shut down socket connections. Being backgrounded should be sufficient. The deep sleep idea might explain some edge case that is causing them not to be restored later. Also of interest would be to turn on internal logging with `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)` (my memory of the syntax is a bit hazy). That could offer some clues on restart of what's happening behind the scenes and why the connection isn't restored.

Comment: Note that since firebase 9.0.0 the setLogLevel command is now: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);`