# Access Firebase Database from a background service in android

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created a FirebaseDatabase instance in one activity and then a reference using it,now I want to access the database from a background service.

In Activity

```
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
.....

mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();`
```

In Similar way in an Intent Service
I want to write to database from the background service as well as from activity
also.So where I am going wrong.
Please help.It might be a silly question but I am stuck and can't proceed untill it is resolved.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691306/background-service-with-firebase-childeventlistener-not-working-after-few-minute

Answer (score 0):

you can start the `ChildEventListener` at the `onStartCommand` of your service and implement what you to do there and it will work as it's on the foreground .

you send data to service :

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, Myservice.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("extra", data);
this.startService(serviceIntent);
```

and receive the data at the service :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // read extra from activity
    String data = intent.getStringExtra("extra");
    // your firebase code here
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: please explain a bit ,if possible i am a newbie