# AddValueEventListener called multiple times on background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ValueEventListener userNavListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.v(Tag, "Called Multiple Times");
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(userNavListener);
}
```

What I want to :
- Apply a **single instance of addValueEventListener**  on background
- Therefore, I do **not** want to use **onDestroy()** method

The problem is the **Log.v** printed **more than once when the data changed only once** if I do this:
   - I open the application,
   - I close the application again,
   - And I open the application again,
   - Then the problem occurs, which is **onDataChange** the Log printed **three times**.

Is there a solution for me to prevent this?

Thank you for your time to read this question and please answer my question if you know the answer.

Comment: If you don't want Firebase to trigger data sync events, then don't use it to store your data. That's just how it's built...

Comment: @cricket_007 the problem is the Log.v is called more than once when the data changed only once.

Comment: Then the data isn't actually changed once

Comment: Not clear why that's an actual problem, though. The data will always be updated to what's in Firebase. Show a [mcve] of the actual code to show why you can't have the data updated multiple times

Comment: ry add an addValueEventListener in your MainActivity, then try to open your app, and close it again, and open it again, then change the database to trigger the eventListener, then see what the Log says, the Log will print 3 times when the database changed

Answer (score 2):

*You must have to remove eventListeners while they are no longer needed.*

Safe place is to do it in `onDestroy()`

```
@Override
public void onDestory() {
    if (mDatabase!= null && userNavListener!= null) {
        mDatabase.removeEventListener(userNavListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: but I want to let it listen on background, how can I achieve it without calling onDestroy() ?

Comment: @Raika then don't remove it

Comment: If there is specific need, you need to create a service to listen in a background.

Comment: Can u teach me how to create a service that trigger only once with android studio ?

Comment: Here is a question for that and what causes the problem in Oreo versions. Follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691306/background-service-with-firebase-childeventlistener-not-working-after-few-minute

Answer (score 2):

If you want to listen only once then please use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `ValueEventListener`

The `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` reads the data only once. So you can use it like this:

```
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(userNavListener)
```

Comment: I want to use just one instance of addValueEventListener, but the listener called multiple times when the data changed, in this question it print the Log.v three times if you open the application twice, and print five times if you open the application three times.

Comment: Did you try my answer, it reads data once so only one time..thats the whole point of addlistenerforsinglevalueevent to read the data once, if you use singlevalueevent `Log.v` will only be called once since data will be changed only once

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, u should try add an addValueEventListener in your MainActivity, then try to open your app, and close it again, and open it again, then change the database to trigger the eventListener, then see what the Log says, the Log will print 3 times when the database changed

Comment: yes I know that, but I told you to use addListenerForSingleValueEvent. But for some reason you dont want to use it

Comment: Because I want to listen to the database when it changed

Comment: yes and thats what that listener does it listens to the database when it changes.. addListenerForSingleValueEvent but it will print the Log one time